# Selenium Webdriver Chrome doesn't work without sudo

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using the same cod for almost a year, and the selenium Webdriver doesn't work all of sudden.
Finally I've found that **the code is not working without sudo option**

```
sudo python3.6 myCode.py # this works
python3.6 myCode.py # this doesn't work
```

**The thing is I'm using Jupyter notebook.**
Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue?
Here's my code below

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)
userAgent = ua.random

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-gpu') 
chrome_options.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')  
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/my/path/to/chromedriver-103',
                          options=chrome_options)
```

Here is my error message below;

```
~/yerinvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Comment: Where is '/my/path/to/chromedriver-103'

Comment: It's located under my 'home' path (home/folder1/folder2/chromedriver-103)

Comment: Please share the error that you get when you run without sudo

Comment: Update the question with he error stacktrace.